Making a Form stay on top of the desktop, and transparent where it intersects with other applications
I'm trying to do this with visual studio C# form application. I'm wondering if this is possible. What I want to do is to keep the program on top of the desktop and below all other programs. I'm working on it but the problem is that when the programs are on top the form becomes invisible, but I'm trying to make only the part of the form that intersects with the applications invisible. Is this possible?
(I want to create a functionality similar to a folder, but as a pop-up that opens with a single click. It should behave like a folder in that it can be opened, closed, and moved around, but it will appear as a pop-up window rather than a traditional folder window.)

Is this a WinForm, WPF, or UWP?

C# is a Windows form application (Winform).
